# How to I make an inner promise finish looping before checking a condition?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am still new to Promises and async coding in JavaScript. I am trying to create a function that returns a promise that iterate through an array of objects with a `setTimeout`. On each element, I will pass it to another function that returns a Promise. If the element doesn't satisfy a condition, I put it into another array and pass that new array into the function for a recursive call 10 more times until it satisfy the condition. Here is the code:

```
const promiseFunc = (item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do something

    if (some_kind_of_error) {
      return reject(the_error);
    } else {
      return resolve({
        itemName: item.name,
        status: (item.isComplete === 'complete')
      });
    }

  });
};

const func2 = (listOfItems, count) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (count > 10) {
      reject(new Error("Too many attempts."));
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      const newList = [];
      listOfItems.forEach(item => {
        promiseFunc(item)
          .then(result => {
            if(result.isCompleted !== true) {
              newList.push(item);
            }
          });
      });

      if (newList.length === 0) {
        return resolve(true);
      } else {
        console.log('Calling func2 again');
        return func2(newList, count+1);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
};
```

The problem is that when I run the `func2` function, I always get `true` even if it is suppose to recurse.

When I tried to log things out, I notice that the message `Calling func2 again` was not logged out in the terminal. This means that no matter what, the condition for checking `newList` will always be empty hence it is always resolving `true` and never going to the `else` statement.

Can someone please explain why this is the current behavior? How do I make it so that my `func2` will wait for the execution of `if (newList.length === 0)` until my `forEach` loop is done?

Comment: When you use setTimeout here what happens. The script will be proccessed until last line and when ever it finds a settimeout function it will add it to a queue which will be handled later at the end of the execution by the queue scheduler.

Comment: My suggestion is in this case you should use asyns await or Promise.all.